# How can I log the Glassfish domain?

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, appserver

I do a bit of logging in a ServletFilter to log which web services are being called, response times, etc, and I would ideallly like to log the domain name of the running Glassfish server. But so far I have not been able to come up with any way of programmatically access this info.

Do any of you know of a way to access this info from the currently running web application?

[org.glassfish.admin.amx.base.DomainRoot](http://javadoc.glassfish.org/v3/apidoc/org/glassfish/admin/amx/base/DomainRoot.html) seems to have some methods that might give some info, but I have no idea on what classes implement these interfaces.

Comment: I found a somewhat hackish way to retrieve the domain name by retrieving the system properties:
`System.getProperty("catalina.base").split("/")` will get you a string array of directory names, where the last element is the name of the domain. Hopefully someone has a better way of doing this. Not answering my own question for a few days to allow for some better solutions.

Comment: Unless you are writing these files to a different file than the server.log, the path to the log file usually has the name of the domain embedded into the path.  The log for domain foo usually ends up in the file named glassfish/domains/foo/logs/server.log...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from a system property:

```
String instanceRoot = System.getProperty("com.sun.aas.instanceRoot");
```

For my glassfish installation this results in:

*C:\glassfishv3\glassfish\domains\domain1*

There is a related property called instanceName:

```
String instanceName = System.getProperty("com.sun.aas.instanceName");
```

which results in the output

*server*

Comment: Yeah, I saw there were a lot of entries in System.getProperties() that all had the same value. I just was not sure which one was _more_ correct than the others. Awarding you the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Recently I came across the following page: ["Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call sun Packages"](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html). Don't know if this recommendation is for properties too. That would be a point for the catalina.base property. But isn't catalina related to Tomcat?

Comment: I did not think about the catalina name belonging to another app server. Good point. instanceName sound better. No clue about the sun.* properties point, though. Thanks anyway :)